# Скрипт выпадающего окна

Tags: jquery

Скрипт выпадающего окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[17 всплывающих и модальных окон jquery CSS для сайта](http://kotweb.ru/for_web_developers/must_have/26-17-vsplyvayuschih-i-modalnyh-okon-jquery-css-dlya-sayta.html)

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью css, например:

```
<style>
.block .h_block{
    display: none;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
}
.block p:hover  ~ .h_block{
    display:block;
    }
</style>
    <div class="block">
        <p>Режим работы</p>
        <div class="h_block">80:00 до 20:00</div>
    </div>
```